# Strange behavior of makefile functions

Tags: makefile

im having issues with $(foreach..) and echo functions.
im trying to iterate over a variable and append it into a file.

here is my code:

```
vars = a b c d
all:
    @$(foreach var, $(vars), echo $(var) >> variables.txt)
```

the generated file looks like

```
a echo  b echo c echo d
```

i have no idea why it prints also the word "echo" and why it is on the same line.

Im working on Windows, on linux the results are as expected.

what am i missing here?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny thing about output redirection. You can put it at the end of a command:

```
echo a b c >> filename
```

Or in the *middle* of a command:

```
echo a b >> filename c
```

Or in *multiple places:*

```
echo a >> filename b >> filename c >> filename
```

and it does exactly the same thing.

In your makefile, this:

```
$(foreach var, $(vars), echo $(var) >> variables.txt)
```

is a *Make* iteration. (The shell has no such command as `foreach`), and it expands into this:

```
echo a >> variables.txt echo b >> variables.txt echo c >> variables.txt echo d >> variables.txt
```

which, as we've seen, is equivalent to:

```
echo a echo b echo c echo d >> variables.txt
```

So the shell dutifully echoes `a echo b echo c echo d` and redirects it to `variables.txt`.

**EDIT:** The simplest way to get the effect you want is to add a semicolon:

```
vars = a b c d
all:
    @$(foreach var, $(vars), echo $(var) >> variables.txt;)
```

Comment: thanks!
you have an idea how i could implement what i need?

Comment: @Guy: Do you want to iterate over the variable in Make or in DOS?

Comment: im calling make from cmd